# OpenMP STL set container iterator

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, openmp

I have a similar problem as the question asked here -[OpenMP parallel thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207909/openmp-parallel-thread).  I would hope to parallelize the for loop involves the std::set iterator.  So I am trying to study the answer provided by @Hristo lliev.  Something I am not quite sure.

If a thread does not get to pick a task, then its "worst_q" should be the original number when it enters the critical section.  But if a thread pick up a task, and the "t_worst_q" will be changed inside the task, then when this thread enters the critical section, this "t_worst_q" will remain the same as it was within the task construct, Am I correct ?  However, I used an example, it does not appear like this way, maybe I am still missing something.

Comment: That answer was terribly wrong. I've just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way you explain it is how "Hristo Iliev" wanted it to work. Unfortunately, he got several things about tasks wrong:

His so-called "barrier" using `taskwait` only works for the thread that created the tasks. All other threads run through it. So his whole reduction in the end is useless because most threads execute it *before* they actually do any work. The "taskwait" was designed to help to account for data dependencies (very useful [in recursive functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-7883/girtd/index.html)!), that's why it works the way it does.

The only reason that the program works sometimes, even without a functional reduction in the end, is that his first mistake is partially cancelled out by a second mistake: The variable `t_worst_q` within the task references the one from the thread that generated the task and therefore acts as a global variable. But then, of course, we have a race condition in the `std::min`, which still lets the code fail sometimes.

So in effect his code is equivalent to the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   // Create tasks
   #pragma omp single nowait
   {
      for(std::set<size_t>::const_iterator it=mesh->NEList[vid].begin();
          it!=mesh->NEList[vid].end(); ++it) {
         size_t elem = *it;
         #pragma omp task shared(worst_q)
         worst_q = std::min(worst_q, mesh->element_quality(elem));
      }
   }
}
```

This, as stated before, has the problem of having a race condition in the access to `worst_q` when executing the `std::min`. If the function `mesh->element_quality` is computationally expensive compared to the `std::min` function, then a simple solution is a critical section around the `std::min` part (after having executed `mesh->element_quality` outside the critical section). If, on the other hand, `mesh->element_quality` isn't more expensive than `std::min`, then the critical section will kill the parallelism. But in this case the function `mesh->element_quality` is so cheap that the overhead for managing the tasks will eat up all the potential speed-up anyway.