# OpenMP v.2.0 or Boost thread 1.59

Tags: c++, openmp, boost-thread, boost-mutex

I am wondering how I can parallelise for loop below in a secure way. I found some possible solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207909/openmp-parallel-thread) . However I am limited to use OpenMP version 2.0 and Boost version 1.59.

algorithm explanation:

It iterates over all of my triangles which lie within the bounding box, then it checks possibility of the intersection (with a unique triangle) in **_considerTriangle** function. Finally in the **_considerTriangle**, if a triangle is intersected it inserts triangle to a set container **intersectedTri**.

```
//Iterating through every triangle
std::set<Triangle> intersectedTri;
for(IntersectedTrianglesIterator it=tree.Begin_IteratorByBoundingBox(bbox_min,bbox_max);it!=tree.End_IteratorByBoundingBox(bbox_min,bbox_max);++it)
            _ConsiderTriangle(it->GetTriangle());
```

I am wonderying how I can paralllise it safely.

Comment: You have to provide more information about your code. It is completely unclear what the underlying data structures are (`tree`), how expensive certain operations are (`IntersectedTrianglesIterator::operator++` vs `_ConsiderTriangle`, `GetTriangel`), what state is modified during an iteration, whether `IntersectedTrianglesIterator` is a random access iterator, .... Pleas provide an [mcve].

Comment: BTW: OpenMP 2.0 is more than **14 years** old. Do you seriously have no newer version available?

Comment: I use Visual Studio, and as you now even VS2015 wont support any newer version of the openMP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any method, as long as you synchronize the insertion into intersectedTri.

```
// globals
boost::mutex mut;

// inside func
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut);
intersectedTri.insert(tri);
```